# Pig Service Check failed using - User: rm/sandbox.hortonworks.com@HDP-SANDBOX is not allowed to impersonate ambari-qa

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, ambari

I ran pig service check using Ambari but it failed and got below exception.

```
2016-04-09 20:35:19,399 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Cleaning up the staging area /user/ambari-qa/.staging/job_1460043791266_0012
2016-04-09 20:35:19,407 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:pigSmoke.sh got an error while submitting 
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1460043791266_0012 to YARN : User: rm/sandbox.hortonworks.com@HDP-SANDBOX is not allowed to impersonate ambari-qa
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1460043791266_0012 to YARN : User: rm/sandbox.hortonworks.com@HDP-SANDBOX is not allowed to impersonate ambari-qa
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.submitApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.submitApplication(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:290)
    ... 16 more
2016-04-09 20:35:19,410 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1460043791266_0012
2016-04-09 20:35:19,410 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases A,B
2016-04-09 20:35:19,410 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M:
```

Any pointer will be very much helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of property "hadoop.proxyuser.yarn.groups" in the core-site.xml? Check the configs in the ambari ui: HDFS -> Configs -> Advanced Tab -> Custom core-site. What version of HDP is this?

Comment: Looks like this property wasnt defined. Thanks @cjackson. I configured property that you mentioned and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the property "hadoop.proxyuser.yarn.groups" in the core-site.xml, is it configured? You can check the configs in the ambari ui: HDFS -> Configs -> Advanced Tab -> Custom core-site. You may want to set the value of the property to `"*"` to see if that solves the issue. If it does you can tighten security by defining only particular groups, instead of all groups (`*`).